# Does MongoDB not update index entries upon document deletion?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

we're using MongoDb 4.0 with Spring Data MongoDB and we noticed that when doing some housekeeping by batch-deleting millions of documents using external Studio3T that all index entries on all indexes stayed untouched. I read lots of MongoDb documentation regarding this but couldn't find any reference to that circumstance.

If this code does not trigger an index update, then which code does?

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("modifiedAt").lte(LocalDateTime.now()));

// Does not remove index entries
mongoTemplate.findAllAndRemove(query, MyModel.class);  

// Does not either
mongoTemplate.remove(query, MyModel.class); 

// Does not either
mongoTemplate.findAll(MyModel.class).forEach(mongoTemplate::remove);
```

Having an effective mechanic of removing documents for housekeeping purposes and having their index entries removed at the same time is important to us as the Index size is growing and does not fit in memory anymore. Therefore we're required to scale up our hardware here which is more expensive unnecessarily.

I know there are ways to trigger this manually, e. g. dropping indexes and recreating them, or using the `compact` administrative function. However in a 24/7 onlineshop use case this seems rather unpractical.

Comment: What do you mean, "does not remove index entries"? Documents are gone and index points to invalid locations now? This can't be. Can you make a [mcve]?

Comment: Index size doesn't change. That makes me assume the index entries are not touched. Running compact on the collection afterwards fixes it.

Comment: I assure you, index entries are removed properly.

Comment: Shouldn't index size reduce accordingly? I batch-deleted 10 mio. documents and index size remains the same.

Comment: No, not necessarily. That space will be reused for future new entries. Running defragmentation on each delete is very expensive.

Comment: I think I got it. So the way it works is that the index entries are deleted but their space is not freed, thus leaving "gaps" between remaining index entries? Why is this not documented anywhere since this space is still "blocked on disk and memory" and cannot be used by the working set I suppose?

Comment: It is documented in the Storage FAQ: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/storage/#how-do-i-reclaim-disk-space-in-wiredtiger

Comment: The thing that is not documented there afaics is what happens to memory consumption, which is really what OP's main stated concern is. Are the bytes represented in RAM with gaps or are the  gabs reclaimable for other purposes? The FAQ doesn't go into such details.